# Haskell: Defaulting constraints to type

Tags: haskell, typeclass

Consider this example:

```
applyKTimes :: Integral i => i -> (a -> a) -> a -> a
applyKTimes 0 _ x = x
applyKTimes k f x = applyKTimes (k-1) f (f x)

applyThrice :: (a -> a) -> a -> a
applyThrice = applyKTimes 3
```

The `3` in `applyThrice` is defaulted by GHC to an `Integer` as shown when compiling with `-Wall`:

```
Warning: Defaulting the following constraint(s) to type 'Integer'
         'Integral t'
           arising from a use of 'applyKTimes'
```

So I guess that `Integer` is the default `Integral a => a`.

- Is there a way to define "default types" for other constraints too?
- Is using default types bad practice? (it does complain when using `-Wall`..)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yes, [you can](http://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/decls.html#default-decls), although it's not quite so simple as adding a default per typeclass, and it only works for `Num` and its subclasses in the `Prelude` and standard libraries. The syntax is `default (t1, ..., tn)`, and only one such declaration can be used per module.

Adding `default (Int)`, for example, would change the default for `Integral` in your code to `Int`.

The default default of `(Integer, Double)` isn't just a GHC policy: it's from the [Haskell 98 Report](http://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/). (GHCi does have [extended default rules](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/6.6/html/users_guide/ch03s04.html#extended-default-rules), though.)

Here's [a discussion](http://hackage.haskell.org/trac/haskell-prime/wiki/Defaulting) of some of the problems with the current system.