# Why are polymorphic values not inferred in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, polymorphism, type-inference, monomorphism-restriction

Numeric literals have a polymorphic type:

```
*Main> :t 3
3 :: (Num t) => t
```

But if I bind a variable to such a literal, the polymorphism is lost:

```
x = 3
...
*Main> :t x
x :: Integer
```

If I define a function, on the other hand, it is of course polymorphic:

```
f x = 3
...
*Main> :t f
f :: (Num t1) => t -> t1
```

I could provide a type signature to ensure the `x` remains polymorphic:

```
x :: Num a => a
x = 3
...
*Main> :t x
x :: (Num a) => a
```

But why is this necessary? Why isn't the polymorphic type inferred?

Comment: Would it make any difference? (I really don't know, although I suspect not)

Comment: It does make a difference; I want the type to remain as general as possible.

Comment: Come again? No matter whether `x` is `Integer` or `Num a => a`, you can pass it to any function which expects a `Num`. Functions have to be generic, values don't.

Comment: @delnan: But you can't pass it to a function that expects an `Int`.

Comment: @sepp2k: Ah, that's the missing piece. Thanks.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

It's the [monomorphism restriction](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Monomorphism_restriction) which says that all values, which are defined without parameters and don't have an explicit type annotation, should have a monomorphic type. This restriction can be disabled in ghc and ghci using `-XNoMonomorphismRestriction`.

The reason for the restriction is that without this restriction `long_calculation 42` would be evaluated twice, while most people would probably expect/want it to only be evaluated once:

```
longCalculation :: Num a => a -> a
longCalculation = ...

x = longCalculation 42

main = print $ x + x
```

Comment: Ah yes, the dreaded monomorphism restriction... I've heard of this but never looked into what it was exactly. Thanks!

Comment: If I added explicit type signatures to this, would it still be evaluated twice, with the no monomorphism restriction extension?

Comment: @JustinL If it has a polymorphic type, it will be evaluated twice. If it has a monomorphic type, it won't. The monomorphism restriction only affects whether it will get a monomorphic or polymorphic type without annotations. If you add annotations, the monomorphism restriction makes no difference.

Comment: Why can't it just evaluate and store it for each type?

Comment: @PyRulez, it might, if optimizations are enabled and work in the right way in that case. The specialization pass may take care of that.

Comment: Could you explain why it needs to be evaluated twice?

Comment: @Praxeolitic `x :: T1` and `x :: T2` (where T1 and T2 are different instances of `Num`) are different things (they'd have different types and memory representation and possibly even different values sematically), so you can't just store them as a single value. So `x` needs to be implemented as a function (taking the desired instance as an argument). Theoretically that function could cache its result per instance (so `(x :: T1, x :: T2, x :: T2)` would lead to two calculations instead of threel, but GHC does not do that.

Answer (score 19):

To expand on sepp2k's answer a bit: if you try to compile the following (or load it into GHCi), you get an error:

```
import Data.List (sort)
f = head . sort
```

This is a violation of the monomorphism restriction because we have a class constraint (introduced by `sort`) but no explicit arguments: we're (somewhat mysteriously) told that we have an `Ambiguous type variable` in the constraint `Ord a`.

Your example (`let x = 3`) has a similarly ambiguous type variable, but it doesn't give the same error, because it's saved by [Haskell's "defaulting" rules](http://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/decls.html):

> Any monomorphic type variables that
>   remain when type inference for an
>   entire module is complete, are
>   considered *ambiguous*, and are resolved
>   to particular types using the
>   defaulting rules (Section 4.3.4).

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2861988/haskell-defaulting-constraints-to-type/2862060#2862060) for more information about the defaulting rules—the important point is that they only work for certain numeric classes, so `x = 3` is fine while `f = sort` isn't.

As a side note: if you'd prefer that `x = 3` end up being an `Int` instead of an `Integer`, and `y = 3.0` be a `Rational` instead of a `Double`, you can use a "default declaration" to override the default defaulting rules:

```
default (Int, Rational)
```

Comment: When I put `f = head . sort` in a file and try to load it, I get an error, but when I type `let f = head . sort` in GHCi I get no error, and the resulting binding has this type: `f :: [()] -> ()`. What's up with that??

Comment: @pelotom: It's because of GHCi's [extended default rules](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/6.12.2/html/users_guide/interactive-evaluation.html#extended-default-rules).