# Type inference subtleties

Tags: haskell, parsec

I'm having some difficulty with understanding why the inferred type signature is different from what I would expect. Let's have an example (I tried to make it as short as possible):

```
import Control.Applicative
import Data.Word
import Text.ParserCombinators.Parsec
import Text.ParserCombinators.Parsec.Token
import Text.Parsec.Language (emptyDef)
import Text.Parsec.Prim
import Data.Functor.Identity

--parseUInt' :: Num b => ParsecT String u Identity b
parseUInt' = fromInteger <$> decimal (makeTokenParser emptyDef)
--parseUInt1 = fromInteger <$> decimal (makeTokenParser emptyDef)
--parseUInt2 = fromInteger <$> decimal (makeTokenParser emptyDef)

parsePairOfInts = do
    x <- parseUInt'
    char ','
    y <- parseUInt'
    return $ (x, y)

parseLine :: String -> Either ParseError (Word32, Word8)
parseLine = parse parsePairOfInts "(error)"

main = print . show $ parseLine "1,2"
```

This code does NOT compile:

```
test.hs:21:19:
    Couldn't match type ‘Word32’ with ‘Word8’
    Expected type: Parsec String () (Word32, Word8)
      Actual type: ParsecT String () Identity (Word32, Word32)
    In the first argument of ‘parse’, namely ‘parsePairOfInts’
    In the expression: parse parsePairOfInts "(error)"
Failed, modules loaded: none.
```

But if I uncomment the type signature of `parseUInt'` it compiles just fine.

At the same time, if I query type information in GHCi, it looks like this:

```
λ>:t (fromInteger <$> decimal (makeTokenParser emptyDef))
(fromInteger <$> decimal (makeTokenParser emptyDef))
  :: Num b => ParsecT String u Identity b
```

But if I do NOT specify the type signature explicitly, the 'b' type is fixed to `Word32` somehow.

If I replace `parseUInt'` with two different (but still the same implementation) functions `parseUInt1` and `parseUInt2`, the code compile too.

I thought that if I don't specify a function's type, the inferred type must be the least restrictive (`Num b =>...`) but it's not the case somehow.

What I'm really missing here?

Comment: This is definitely [Monomorphism restriction](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Monomorphism_restriction).

If I add `{-# LANGUAGE NoMonomorphismRestriction #-}`, it starts compiling.

Many thanks to @GabrielGonzalez and @amalloy. I wish I can upvote your answers but don't have enough "reputation" yet.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think this is the dreaded `MonomorphismRestriction` in action.  If you don't provide a type signature then `ghc` tries to infer a concrete type signature if the function is instantiated to a concrete type elsewhere in the code.  `ghc` sees that you use the function to parse a `Word32` as the first line of `parsePairOfInt`s and then fixes `parseUInt'` to that type before reaching the second usage of `parseUInt'` two lines down.  This then leads to a type error because the type has already been instantiated to `Word32` and now the type needs to be `Word8`.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like the [monomorphism restriction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4179453/why-are-polymorphic-values-not-inferred-in-haskell) again. You defined something that doesn't "look" like a polymorphic value, so the compiler inferred a monomorphic type for it.

This turns out not to be the type you wanted, so you'll have to be clear that you intend the polymorphism, by adding a type signature.