# Couldn't match expected type ‘a’ with actual type ‘Double’:

Tags: haskell

I declared the type declaration by checking it from ghci but loading the module gives error:

```
even-fibbanaci-sum.hs:7:12: error:
     Couldn't match expected type ‘a’ with actual type ‘Double’
     ‘a’ is a rigid type variable bound by
       the type signature for:
         getFib :: forall b a. (Integral b, Floating a) => b -> a
       at even-fibbanaci-sum.hs:4:12
     In the expression: ((phi ^ n) - (minusphi ^ n)) / sqrt 5
     In an equation for ‘getFib’:
         getFib n = ((phi ^ n) - (minusphi ^ n)) / sqrt 5    • Relevant bindings include
       getFib :: b -> a (bound at even-fibbanaci-sum.hs:5:1)
```

Here is my code

```
phi = (1 + sqrt 5) / 2
minusphi = (1 - sqrt 5) / 2

getFib ::  (Integral b,Floating a) => b -> a
getFib n = ((phi ^ n) - (minusphi ^ n)) / sqrt 5

fibSum :: (Integral b,Floating a) => b -> a
fibSum x =sum $ map getFib [2,5..x]
```

but when it in ghci it works fine.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is an example of the [monomorphism restriction](https://wiki.haskell.org/Monomorphism_restriction).

When you load a file into `ghci` or compile it with `ghc`, the monomorphism restriction is enabled, which means that you get certain defaulting rules in type inference. In this case, Haskell infers that `phi` and `minusphi` have type `Double` instead of `Floating a => a`, which is what you wanted.

In `ghci` itself though, the monomorphism restriction is not enabled, so the most general types *are* inferred.

To fix this in your example above, just add the explicit type annotation:

```
phi, minusphi :: Floating a => a
phi = (1 + sqrt 5) / 2
minusphi = (1 - sqrt 5) / 2
```

[Here's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4179453/why-are-polymorphic-values-not-inferred-in-haskell) a previous question which has a better answer IMO.